# Secure flag for ASPXAUTH Cookie in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

We have an Application which is developed using ASP.NET MVC3.  Penetration-test done by an IBM AppScan tool.

Issue has been reported and it was ASPXAUTH is not secure. When I checked on the browser's developer tools, there are some cookies with Secure flag. But ASPXAUTH was not one of them.

[image]

Already I have included below line of code in Web.Config file.

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>
```

**Note :** We are not using Forms Authentication for login. We are using Signle Sign-On Mechanism.

What is the correct way to mark ASPXAUTH as secure?

Comment: What does your form tag look like? - the `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"` bit?

Comment: @Alex - Sorry I forgot to mention, our application does not use Forms Authentication.

Comment: What auth mechanism are you using

Comment: @Alex - We are using Single Sign On login mechanism.

Comment: please can you edit your question to show how you're configuring this

Comment: @Alex - This is the only line I have added under <system.web> tag.
<httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>

Comment: `using Single Sign On login mechanism` - how is that configured?!

Comment: @Alex - Sorry, I could not get your question here. We have implemented authentication validation logic in MVC Controller class.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in Global.asax.cs file.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
                    {
                        Response.Cookies[s].Secure = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not working for me, not using form authentication but using centralized login. Added below code:

```cs
foreach (string sCookie in httpCookies.AllKeys)
{
    if (sCookie == FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName || sCookie.ToLower() == "asp.net_sessionid")
    {
        httpCookies[sCookie].Secure = true;
    }                    
}
```